# how widespread is support for @media query with min-aspect-ratio and max-aspect-ratio

Tags: css

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio) has a lot of question marks in compat table.

caniuse does not seem to have a page for this specifically.

Googling around, I can't find much, but find some people writing about it as if they are using it now, and it works.

Is it supported by recent Chrome? iOS Safari? Android? Is there a good polyfill?